# cURL SFTP not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: ubuntu, curl, server, ftp, sftp

I am trying to use sftp with cURL to upload files to my webserver, if I run `curl -V` on my server I get this output

```
curl 7.47.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.8.0
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap pop3 rtsp scp sftp smtp telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile libz UnixSockets
```

But if I try to upload files to my server using sftp:// for the `curl` URL I get this output after adding the `-v` option to the curl command:

```
* Protocol sftp not supported or disabled in libcurl
* Closing connection -1
curl: (1) Protocol sftp not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall cURL with no luck. I have also tried to reboot my server and that did not fix it. 
I've tried to install sftp on both cURL version 7.47 and 7.57 but neither work

Comment: I suspect you have two different curl versions installed on that machine...

Comment: @DanielStenberg, I uninstalled the cURL version I had installed using `make uninstall` in the curl directory, then I tried `curl -V` and there was no version installed I then reinstalled curl and tried again and I got the same error when trying to upload the file